# Still cannot mount android phone to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mount, android, mtp

I'm sounding like a broken record! I have been trying to mount my Galaxy S3 to 14.04 for months now. I followed suggestions from community members, all to no avail. Now I have a new phone - Galaxy S5. Same problem. I can see the phone, folders and files, but cannot open them. See screenshot.[image: Picture folder and viewer]

Comment: Followed what suggestions? Can you see the files when you copythem to your computer?

Comment: This may an issue with 'viewing' image files. *You need to first verify if issue relates to file access.* Please also identify which Android/MTP version is on the smartphone.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Galaxy S5 and I found that jmtpfs worked fine (whereas standard mtpfs didn't work).

One off:

```
sudo apt-get install jmtpfs
mkdir /path/to/my/mountpoint
```

Each time you want to connect:

```
[Connect USB cable]
sudo jmtpfs -o allow_other /path/to/my/mountpoint
```

when finished:

```
sudo fusermount -u /path/to/my/mountpoint
```