# Problems copying files with MTP from Samsung Galaxy S5 mini to Kubuntu 15.10

Tags: android, mtp

I'm having real problems copying files from my phone (Samsung S5 mini) to my laptop (Kubuntu 15.10). I've tried many of the suggestions on other sites, such as

- [udev rules and installing more mtp packages](https://askubuntu.com/a/308366/176104)

I can connect and browse files, but when I try to open or copy them, usually my CPU goes into overdrive for a bit, and then eventually gives up with this message:
`The process for the mtp protocol died unexpectedly.`
Occasionally, however, it does work. I have no idea what the difference is. Once, after a successful copy, I changed directory and tried to copy some other files, and the mtp connection died. Obviously, the setup here hadn't changed in the meantime.

`mtp-detect` gives the following result
    libmtp version: 1.1.9

```
Listing raw device(s)
Device 0 (VID=04e8 and PID=6860) is a Samsung Galaxy models (MTP).
   Found 1 device(s):
   Samsung: Galaxy models (MTP) (04e8:6860) @ bus 4, dev 9
Attempting to connect device(s)
ignoring libusb_claim_interface() = -6PTP_ERROR_IO: failed to open session, trying again after resetting USB interface
LIBMTP libusb: Attempt to reset device
LIBMTP PANIC: failed to open session on second attempt
Unable to open raw device 0
OK.
```

I'd like to avoid things like `adb`/`gvfs`/`fuser`, since mtp *should* just work. I'll fall back to bluetooth if I really can't figure it out.

Other things which don't work:

- Like [this guy](https://askubuntu.com/a/424169/176104), I can't seem to connect at all through USB2.
- If I switch the phone into camera mode it doesn't get detected at all.

### Edit:

I've discovered a [duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/650063/still-cannot-mount-android-phone-to-ubuntu-14-04/695638). That question was first, and it has one answer, but I think I provided a bit more information. What's the recommended procedure here? Should I close this as a dupe? Add a link from their question to here? Ideally I think I would put a bounty on the other question. (This added question might be a candidate for the meta section, but I would guess that it is a duplicate there, which seems like recursive meta and might make my brain explode.)